# Access a DB from two different server using CGI

Tags: database, cgi

Need to access a DB from two different servers  [ 123.123.125.12 , 75.182.16.36 ] using CGI in a single file

Comment: omg...it's been forever since I've heard of cgi - I was forever thankful when ADO and ASP.Net were released.

Answer (score 0):

By CGI, you mean Common Gateway Interface, right? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

CGI is an interface. You can use it with many different software packages/languages. Do you want to use it with Perl, PHP, Ruby on Rails, Java? Something else?

Here's an article on using Perl to access a database: http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2003/10/23/databases.html

Larry